# Why use gdalwarp add -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS is slow than don't use this option?

Tags: qgis, gdalwarp

I try to test then reproject run time by use QGIS's toolbox-->Warp(reproject) on Windows 10, I find use gdalwarp add option -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS is slow than don't use this option. this is the GDAL command in log:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4528 -r near -multi -of GTiff -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -dstalpha GF_Prj.tif GFmutiBig03.tif
```

add -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS this option cost  more run time  than don't add this option,I test many time get same result.

I'm curious about what caused this. I thought adding this option would make it run faster, but it didn't.

Comment: It sounds like you're experiencing a situation similar to disc thrashing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science), as each thread is reading/writing to different locations in the files your drive is constantly seeking. Have a look at your task manager and see which component is maxed, it is most likely do be disc access; try reducing the number of cores to half the available and see if that helps. To speed it up process with different source and target drives (both internal, gives a small boost), or get an internal SSD (no seek time), do both for max increase.

Comment: Some tips [here](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#memory-usage).